# How do i track a range of cells using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

in Excel VBA, I would like to track if range A1 to A3 and A7 to A8 is filled with a value. If its filled, i want to show "Ready" in cell B1 else don't show anything in cell B1.

Im not sure how to get this done using excel vba. Pls help me. I have been trying for the past few hours without any luck. Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't think you need VBA to do this. Why don't you use a Formula in Cell B1? Example (Excel 2013): `=IF(AND(A1 <> ""| A2 <> ""| A3 <> "")| "Ready"| "")`

Comment: Thanks for reply. For a start, im playing with displaying some words in cell B1. The program will be doing lots more computation based on the tracked cells. Thus i need to code this in vba.

Comment: Could you add code information what you have tried so far? This will help others to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub DataTest()
    Set r1 = Range("A1")
    Set r2 = Range("A2")
    Set r3 = Range("A3")
    Set r7 = Range("A7")
    Set r8 = Range("A8")
    Set b1 = Range("B1")
    If [r1] <> "" And [r2] <> "" And [r3] <> "" And [r7] <> "" And [r8] <> "" Then
        b1.Value = "Ready"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this isnt the best way to do it, but it works for me. This is what i did.
i used worksheet calculate event to do it. Since i'm tracking cells A1 to A3, i equated their values to cells B1 to B3 respectively. And then i set up this codes to track cells A1 to A3, indirectly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim input_field As Boolean

input_field = True

If IsEmpty(Range("B1")) Or Range("B1").Value = 0 _
   Or IsEmpty(Range("B2")) Or Range("B2").Value = 0 _
   Or IsEmpty(Range("B3")) Or Range("B3").Value = 0 Then
   input_field = False
Else
   input_field = True
End If

If input_field = True Then
 Range("C1") = "Ready"
Else
 Range("C1") = ""
End If

End Sub
```